# How can I compile my Windows program into a single Linux binary that runs with Wine?

Tags: linux, delphi, wine

Just today i checked my ubuntu with installing wine in it ,

Delphi 3 to 7 worked perfectly (Rad studios did not work because they use .net scraps).
But all of the application i made worked perfectly!!!!!
And i heard that it also works well in mac with WineBottler

Is it possible to create a header linux executable and put my vcl application and requird wine stuff into it and distribute as a single executable (.bin)

Comment: Some times it may be impossible i think (may be wrong),because if it can be done easily ; embarcadero could have done it some years ago

Comment: When you say Delphi 3 to 7 "worked perfectly", does that include the debugger? Last time I tried it, the debugger did *not* work.

Comment: I prefer bordaeux with Delphi.

Comment: @dummzeuch you are correct debugger did not work however still a decent ide

Comment: Use CodeTyphon/Lazarus/FreePascal to convert your Delphi application to native Linux application without Wine. You can even develop Linux applications on Windows, and Windows applications on Linux. http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148

Comment: @Jeroen that would be Bordeaux! Do you Beneluxers not drink vino enough to know how to spell the home of claret?!!  ;-)

Comment: Actually, that is part of my word-blindness (there is a hard to spell word for that too <g>). And in hindsight (spelling?) it is a funny mistake too. Like Wine is not an emulator, it is not Bordeaux either (but Bordeaux is Wine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what [winelib](http://ftp.winehq.org/pub/wine/docs/en/winelib-guide.html) is for. However I have never tried it. (Wasn't Kylix Delphi + winelib compiled for Linux?)

Comment: Its not compatible license-wise. Naturally, when someone violates GPL terms, Stallman kills several bunnies.

Comment: You can use GPL licensed products freely until you modify

Comment: @User, Winelib is licensed under the LGPL, not the GPL. You're allowed to link with it all you want without having to release your code under the same license. Vibeeshan, as a developer you wouldn't just be *using* it. You'd be *distributing* programs that *link* to it, and GNU considers that to be creating a *derivative work*. If the library is GPL, then your code must be GPL as well. (But Winelib isn't GPL.)

Comment: @Vibeeshan: Not at all. Modification is allowed. Linking with non-GPL code is not. Also, shareware schemes are disallowed.

Comment: Not so. The ELF binary must be run via wine-preloader.

In other words, it's really no more convenient than using 
wine on a win32 binary.

Answer (score 10):

there is(was) a solution for Linux from Borland, called Kylix. Kylix is based on some older Qt-stuff.
But I would give FreePascal/Lazarus a try, it's pretty cool! and the compiler compiles for many different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Since Wine is now stable (reached the 1.0 version some time ago), it could make sense to ask the user to install it using its Linux packages manager. It's very fast and easy. So Wine will be always up to date, according to the distribution used.

Then it's very easy to install any Windows program with Wine.

Since Delphi executables are [mostly self-contained](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/09/20/Dll-hell%2C-WinSXS-directory-and-Delphi-paradise) (if you don't use the BDE or some external database libraries), your clients will install your Delphi application alla "Windows" way, that is, by running a Setup program from Wine.

And it will work fine, as is.

Using WineLib is not a good idea, even not advised by Wine developers, as far as I remember. At least for closed-source software: in one or two years, perhaps you won't release another version of your program, but Wine and WineLib will have evolved a lot... If you use Wine as an external package, your client can be sure there will be some end user enhancements.

If your software is purely Open Source, then using WineLib could make sense. But even the WineLib headers can evolved, so perhaps your source won't evolve at the same speed...

Comment: The last time I tried WINE it wouldn't schedule more than 1 thread at once which was something of a letdown.

Comment: @David: Wine handle threads, in two modes, depending on the running OS: either wine-kthread or wine-pthread. The new NPTL feature is used on Linux, which works very well. - see http://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/threading

Comment: Well, I was simply creating threads, letting them run, and expecting the system to schedule them onto different cores. Everything was landing on a single core. Clearly something extra was needed but I couldn't work it out!